# Change background color of Layer in the TOC / QgsLayerTreeLayer with pyqgis

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, qt, table-of-contents, pyqt4

I would like to change the background-color (or font color) of some items in the TOC of QGIS:

Example-Mockup:

[image]

I tried several ways but nothing did the trick so far:

```
layer_list = QgsProject.instance().layerTreeRoot().children() 
for lyr in layer_list:        
    if isinstance(lyr, QgsLayerTreeGroup):
        lyr.setProperty("background-color","red")
        #lyr.setBackgroundColor(0, QtGui.QColor('green'))
        #lyr.setStyleSheet("background-color: green;")


    elif isinstance(lyr,QgsLayerTreeLayer):
        if lyr.name()=='Verteiler':
            lyr.setProperty("background-color","red")
            #lyr.setBackgroundColor(0, QtGui.QColor('green'))
            #lyr.setStyleSheet("background-color: green;")
```

I can't use a generic stylesheet like the ones used in the UI-themes, as the background-color should only be changed for some of my layers.

Is this possible?

edit1:

I found one way to change the style of layertree-items in general:

```
from PyQt4.QtGui import QApplication
QApplication.instance().setStyleSheet("QTreeView::item {color:green;}" );
```

Perhaps it would be possible to assign custom properties to some items of the TOC to be able to style only the wanted items.

Comment: The bounty reason is "Canonical answer required"

Comment: You *might* be able to do something by crafting a tailored QFont for `QgsLayerTreeModel.setLayerTreeNodeFont`, I have not tested this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry to say this is *almost* impossible.

The way Qt supports conditional styling with stylesheets is by using `QObject::setObjectName` (see [doc](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-examples.html)) which you cannot do on a tree view item.

Your code does not work because layer tree nodes are not GUI items (more over, this would be cancelled any time the legend view is refreshed, which happen very often).

The [Qt docs](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-examples.html#customizing-qtreeview) describes how customizing tree views with CSS but it cannot be layer-specific as you require.

There would be only 2 options, as far as I see:

1. Code that possibility in QGIS core by creating a new custom property on layer tree node (could be called background-color) and would be used for painting the color (in the `QgsLayerTreeModel::data`)
2. Replace the model of the layer tree view with your own customized model. You'd have to inherit the core model (QgisApp return a non-const pointer to the layer tree view) and reimplement `data` (which is not virtual, so I am not 100% sure it would work). That road is very risky and sounds much more like a hack and I would discourage any plugin to follow that road as it might end to bad user experience in QGIS.

Option 1 would definitely be the way to go, but that means adding this in QGIS core (need to be accepted, you'd have to wait for next release for which new features are accepted: QGIS 3.6 in roughly 5 months).

---

**Another approach** would be to use layer **indicators**.
You can add them on the layer tree using

```
qgis.utils.iface.layerTreeView().addIndicator(node, indicator)
```

See the docs of Python API for [QgsVectorLayerTree](http://qgis.org/api/classQgsLayerTreeView.html) and [QgsVectorLayerTreeIndicator](http://qgis.org/api/classQgsLayerTreeViewIndicator.html)

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I think having the option to highlight layers in the TOC would be a nice core feature.

Comment: here is a PR https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/pull/8142

Comment: in the PR, there is an interesting comment: you could use layer tree indicators, that would be much more appropriate. You can do `qgis.utils.iface.layerTreeView().addIndicator(node, indicator)` See the docs: https://qgis.org/api/classQgsLayerTreeView.html and https://qgis.org/api/classQgsLayerTreeViewIndicator.html